# Randomly colored and randomly sized points in a region

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, random, table

I am trying to show random points with different colors and sizes. However, the following code generates random points with the same color. I want them in different colors.

I think I have a problem with table management.

Please kindly have a look into it. My code is as follows:

```
bounds = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
ℛ = Cuboid @@ Transpose[bounds];
rp = RandomPoint[ℛ, 1000];

Graphics3D[
 Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], PointSize[RandomReal[{0, 0.005}]], 
   Point[rp]}, {1000}]]
```

Comment: Look at `Graphics3D[Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], PointSize[RandomReal[{0, 0.005}]], Point[rp]}, {1}]]` You are using the same 1000 point locations repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[]], PointSize[RandomReal[{0, 0.005}]], 
    Point[#]} & /@ rp]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This could be one way:

```
bounds = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
ℛ = Cuboid @@ Transpose[bounds];
rp = RandomPoint[ℛ, 1000];

Graphics3D[{
  {RandomColor[]
     , AbsolutePointSize[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]]
     , Point[#]} & /@ rp
  , {Opacity[0.2], Lighter@Cyan, ℛ}
  }
 ]
```

[image]